# Printing the second frame of top output

Tags: linux, bash

When I execute the "top" command without any flags, I get

[image: something like this]with about a dozen processes using at least 0.1% memory and CPU.

When I print this to a file using a cronjob set to run every minute, which executes the command below, however, I only get two or three processes using more than 0.1% memory and CPU.

The cronjob executes this command:

`top -b -n 1 | sed -n '8,17p' | sed 's/^ *//' | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/ /", "/g ; s/^/{"/g ; s/$/"},/g ; 1s/^/[/ ; $ s/.$/]/ ; s/"/"pid": "/1 ; s/"/"user": "/5 ; s/"/"pr": "/9 ; s/"/"ni": "/13 ; s/"/"virt": "/17 ; s/"/"res": "/21 ; s/"/"shr": "/25 ; s/"/"s": "/29 ; s/"/"cpu": "/33 ; s/"/"mem": "/37 ; s/"/"time": "/41 ; s/"/"command": "/45 ; s/"\(-\?[0-9]\+\)"/\1/g'`

which takes the first frame of "top" in batch mode and returns it in JSON format, e.g. something like this:

```
[
    {
        "pid": 7303,
        "user": "fahclie+",
        "pr": 39,
        "ni": 19,
        "virt": 255736,
        "res": 14716,
        "shr": 5556,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "400,9",
        "mem": "0,2",
        "time": "210:15.98",
        "command": "FahCore_a4"
    },
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 42040,
        "res": 4664,
        "shr": 2840,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,1",
        "time": "0:01.16",
        "command": "init"
    },
    {
        "pid": 2,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:00.00",
        "command": "kthreadd"
    },
    {
        "pid": 3,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:00.13",
        "command": "ksoftirqd/0"
    },
    {
        "pid": 5,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 0,
        "ni": -20,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:00.00",
        "command": "kworker/0:+"
    },
    {
        "pid": 7,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:03.58",
        "command": "rcu_sched"
    },
    {
        "pid": 8,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:00.00",
        "command": "rcu_bh"
    },
    {
        "pid": 9,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:01.26",
        "command": "rcuos/0"
    },
    {
        "pid": 10,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": 20,
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:00.00",
        "command": "rcuob/0"
    },
    {
        "pid": 11,
        "user": "root",
        "pr": "rt",
        "ni": 0,
        "virt": 0,
        "res": 0,
        "shr": 0,
        "s": "S",
        "cpu": "0,0",
        "mem": "0,0",
        "time": "0:00.51",
        "command": "migration/0"
    }

]
```

Note how from the third processes onward, none of these processes use over 0.0% memory or CPU.

I suspect this is because the first frame of top is the one being written, while during the first frame, top is still gathering process information.

Is there a way to print the second frame to a file instead?

Comment: Please edit the question and provide an accessible URL for the JSON format or best the JSON as readably formated code snippet in the question. Hint: 192.168.0.247 is a private IP ... thanks (noticed the updated URL) - I copied the content inside a code block in your question HTH. So you want more than 10 entries (on that machine at that time), right?

Comment: Oh and what operating system / distribution? On my next Ubuntu server I have `top -b -n 1` nicely print out all processes ...

Comment: This is in Linux Mint 17.3 "Rosa". (Added some more details to the OP)

Comment: When I execute top, the first frame I see shows fewer processes than the next frame. I think this first frame is being written to a file. I'd rather it print the second frame, however, because by then top seems to have have gathered more information about the running processes.

Comment: You know you don't have to run dozens of separate `sed` commands. You can do `sed 'cmd1;cmd2;cmd3;...'`

Comment: `sed -n '8,17p'` means it will only process those 10 lines.

Comment: Memory percentage doesn't require multiple frames. Only CPU percentage does, because it needs to calculate CPU time divided by real time.

Comment: It's not about the number of lines. 10 lines is fine. It's about the content of those lines: I'd like to get those lines from the second frame of top, so as to get some somewhat more meaningful information from it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, didn't know I could concat multiple seds. Edited the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to jamesd in freenode's #bash IRC channel:

First we use `top -b -n 2` to return the first 2 frames.

We then pipe these frames to `grep -A10 'PID USER'` (`10` being the number of trailing context lines after the matching line, and `'PID USER'` the beginning of the headings line), and in turn pipe the result of this to `tail -n 10` to get rid of the headings line.

This shows only the top 10 processes of the second frame of `top`.

`10` can of course be swapped out for the desired number of processes, and `'PID USER'` for whichever fields come first in the headings line of your personal `top` configuration.